# Too many connections error while using mongodb with java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, connection

I use MongoDbFactory to connect to mongodb with Java. But the mongo service throws socket exception at least once every hour. Hence I am forced to restart mongodb service to restore operations. I think that this may be a result of unclosed connections to mongodb from java and also MongoDbFactory do not provide me a function to close a connection. How can I make sure that all connections are closed after a particular session.

This is the code I am using:

```
package com.####.mongo.configuration;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class SpringMongoFeedConfig {

public @Bean
MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "feedDatabase");
}

public @Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(mongoDbFactory(), new MongoMappingContext());
    converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), converter);


    return mongoTemplate; 
}
```

}

And:

```
private String insertFeedsToMongo(FeedMongoDTO feedObject, FeedType type) throws UnknownHostException {
    try {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoFeedConfig.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

        switch (type) {

        case FOLLOW:
            mongoOperation.save(feedObject, "feedsByUid");
            break;

        case GENERAL:
            mongoOperation.save(feedObject, "allFeeds");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return feedObject.getId();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info("insertFeedsToMongo() : mongo Exception - ", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered issues with the `Mongo` object as well. Making sure to call `myMongo.close()` when that particular connection is done resolved it.

I would suggest storing your instances created with `new Mongo()` in your factory function somewhere that would allow it to be closed later <del>(the `SimpleMongoDbFactory` might be just the place for that).</del> Just noted that's a Spring-thing. Suggestion remains: track your `Mongo` instances.

Answer (score 2):

With akaIDIOT's suggestion I have done as following

```
public class FeedMongoOperations {

public static transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FeedMongoOperations.class);

private Mongo mongo;
private SimpleMongoDbFactory dbFactory;
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public boolean openDbConnection() {
    try {
        MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
        options.connectionsPerHost = 100;
        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", options);
        dbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, "feedDatabase");
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbFactory, new MongoMappingContext());
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, converter);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean closeDbConnection() {
    try {
        mongoTemplate = null;
        dbFactory = null;
        mongo.close();

        return true;
    }
}

public String save(FeedMongoDTO feed, String collectionName) {
    try {
        mongoTemplate.save(feed, collectionName);
        return feed.getId();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    } 
}

public FeedMongoDTO getFeed(String mongoId, String collectionName) {

    try {
        FeedMongoDTO feedMongoDTO = mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(mongoId)), FeedMongoDTO.class,
                collectionName);
        return feedMongoDTO;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```